# Azure Configurationmanager GetConfigurationAsync proxy error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm working through the following code

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager

```
            ConfigurationManager<IssuerMetadata> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<IssuerMetadata>(AzureADIssuerMetadataUrl, new IssuerConfigurationRetriever());
            configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
            IssuerMetadata issuerMetadata = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
```

I receive the error

'One or more errors occurred. (IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize&api-version=1.1'.)'

How can I dig digger to understand the error? Is this due to a proxy not being set (I'm running behind a corporate firewall)?

Comment: If you try accessing the metadata directly, e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration, can you?

Comment: yes but the alternative way 'curl' I know I have set to use a proxy.

Comment: Then that is probably the issue. The server needs to be configured to route those requests via your proxy.

Comment: I'm assuming that is the code but don't know how to do it in this interface (thinking it may be encapsulated lower)